# Transforming Arrays into Columns in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

Original Question - [Transform Array into columns in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72092206/transform-array-into-columns-in-bigquery)

Solution suggested in the original question works well when you want to extract the same information from the array elements. But in my case, the information that I want to extract from each array element can be different. For example- If you see the original question, the 3rd Array element we have doesn't have jsonPayload but instead it has nameValuePairs in it. If I use pivot there then unnecessary fields get created. How to avoid them, I know we can use EXCEPT but I don't think that is a good solution because If I have to choose different elements from each array element, it would be really a mess. As I can have 10+ payloads in the payloads array.

SQL -

```
select * from (
  select 
    json_value(payload,'$.pool') as pool,
    json_value(payloadArr, '$.name') as name, 
    json_value(payloadArr, '$.fullpath') as fullPath,
    json_value(payloadArr, '$.jsonPayload.body') as payload,
    json_value(payloadArr, '$.nameValuePairs.data.one') as nv, 
  from  table t
  , unnest(json_extract_array(payload, '$.payloads')) payloadArr
)
pivot (any_value(fullPath) as fullPath , any_value(payload) as payload,  any_value(nv) as nv for name in ('request', 'response', 'attributes') )
```

[image]

Comment: why not use bigquery JS UDF to have more control over the field filters & operations dynamically? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68709560/bigquery-transform-generic-json-to-struct/68718701#68718701

Comment: Hello @arunkindra. Can you let me know if your issue is resolved?

Comment: Hi @KabilanMohanraj it is working fine with the query suggested by Mikhail. The point to note that we need one unique identifier in all the records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
select * from (
  select 
    json_value(payload,'$.pool') as pool,
    json_value(payloadArr, '$.name') as name, 
    json_value(payloadArr, '$.fullpath') as fullPath,
    coalesce(
      json_value(payloadArr, '$.jsonPayload.body'),
      json_value(payloadArr, '$.nameValuePairs.data.one')
    ) as payload, 
  from  table t
  , unnest(json_extract_array(payload, '$.payloads')) payloadArr
)
pivot (any_value(fullPath) as fullPath , any_value(payload) as payload for name in ('request', 'response', 'attributes') )
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Hi @mikhail

There is one problem with both the answer, I have more than one record in my table, it is just returning one record because of aggregate function any_value. How can I apply same operation on each row and get the above desired ans.

Comment: do all records have same pool and name? I thought those two will define the row. isn't this the case?

Comment: These can be the same, so we have one uuid which would be unique between each records. I just added them it is looks working fine.